# Aggregate of OuterRef in Django Subquery

Tags: django, django-subquery

I have the following two models in Django 4.2:

```
class Team(Model):
  members = ManyToManyField(...)
  ...

class Size(Model):
  max_members = PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
  class Meta:
    ordering = [F('max_members').asc(nulls_last=True)]
```

The idea is that each `Team` has a `Size` but I can't (as far as I know) model this as a SQL relation. But that's OK, we can get the size of a team as follows:

```
Size.objects.filter(Q(max_members=None) | Q(max__gte=team.members.count())).first()
```

However if I want to get the size associated with an entire queryset of teams at once, I am stuck. It seems like the following should work:

```
teams.annotate(
  size=Subquery(
     Size.objects.filter(
       Q(max_members=None) | Q(max_members__gte=Count(OuterRef('members')))
     ).values('pk')[:1]
  )
)
```

But this produces invalid SQL (we are using PostGres):

```
SELECT "teams_team".*
       (SELECT U0."id"
        FROM "teams_size" U0
        HAVING (U0."max_members" IS NULL OR U0."max_members" >= (COUNT("teams_teammembers"."user_id")))
        ORDER BY U0."max" ASC NULLS LAST
        LIMIT 1) AS "size"
FROM "teams_team"
         LEFT OUTER JOIN "teams_teammembers" ON ("teams_team"."id" = "teams_teammembers"."team_id")
```

This is missing a `GROUP BY teams_team.id` and the `HAVING` clause should be `WHERE`.

I can get some of the way there with some hacking: if I swap `Count` for `Func(..., function='COUNT')` then Django doesn't realise there is any aggregation and keeps the `WHERE` clause as it should do. But adding the grouping by hand, by setting `qs.query.group_by = ['id']` results in Django automatically also grouping on `teams_teammembers.user_id`. Hence there is one group for every member of the team, and the count is always 1.

I have seen uses of aggregation within subqueries in django code, but never of an `OuterRef` so I assume that is what's going wrong here, hence the title.

Ultimately I want to get the IDs of the sizes so that I can match up the actual size objects with the teams as if this were a real relationship. A solution which somehow added a prefetchable `django.models.ForeignObject` to `Team` to represent the relationship would actually be even better.

If there is no ORM solution then an idea of how to do this with the least amount of custom SQL within Django would be welcome. Failing that we'll just denormalise the relation but we'd rather not at this point.